how can I fit user-defined function to concentration/effect data using nlmer?
Please forgive this naive question. I'm trying to use nlmer to fit the following function to dose-response data. There are 7 levels of concentration ("conc") and two levels of "sugar" (the independent variables): resp=max/(1+EC50^slope/conc^slope). The csv file is arranged thus:
rownumber rat   sugar   conc    resp
r1  rat1    malt    12.5    0
r2  rat2    malt    12.5    0
r3  rat3    malt    12.5    5.3
r4  rat4    malt    12.5    0
r5  rat5    malt    12.5    10
r6  rat6    malt    12.5    0
r7  rat7    malt    12.5    0
r8  rat8    malt    12.5    0
.
.
r104    rat8    suc 400 90
r105    rat1    suc 800 100
r106    rat2    suc 800 75
r107    rat3    suc 800 100
r108    rat4    suc 800 85
r109    rat5    suc 800 100
r110    rat6    suc 800 75
r111    rat7    suc 800 95
r112    rat8    suc 800 100
I tried fitting the eq. with the following:

dat=read.csv(file.choose("C:/CMB files/DOCUMENTS/R-work/wink11/longdatsucmalt1.csv")


)


nform<-~max/(1+EC50^slope/conc^slope)
nfunc<-deriv(nform,namevec=c("max","EC50","slope"),function.arg=c("conc","max","EC50","slope"))
nfit<-nlmer(resp~nfunc(conc,max,EC50,slope)~(max+EC50+slope|sugar),dat,startvec<-c(max=50,EC50=100,slope=2)


)

I get the following error
Error in nlformula(mc <- match.call()) :
is.numeric(nlpars <- start$nlpars) is not TRUE
Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you, Chris
